# disallowed_useragent with Google Drive SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to implement Google Drive SDK in my project but nothing seems to go well, i wanted to upload images and create folder on Google Drive but i am stuck with the error ,which i don't know how to get through, as i found nothing related to the following error.

[image: this]

I have strongly followed [this link for code](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart)

Comment: a clean way is to use gidsignIn instead. I have anwered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654403/403-error-disallowed-useragent/42045386#42045386

Answer (score 1):

Google has updated its security restrictions for OAuth flow. They are not going to allow native web-views to initiate OAuth flows.  You will need to use the OS browsers to do so.

[Modernizing OAuth interactions in Native Apps for Better Usability and Security](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)

You may have to wait for google to update the sample code or figure out how to do it yourself sorry i am not an IOS developer so cant be of any help.

The issue is already logged on the issue forum for Google drive [4919](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4919)

Comment: Already gone through the link given by you, but nothing seems to be helpful their

Comment: Again until google fixes the code there is probably nothing you can do.  The code you are using is probably using a native web-view which you cant use.

Comment: yeah can do nothing but wait for the fix..!

Comment: add your name to the issue request will help get it more attention.  However in my experience Google has code freeze in mid November nothing gets released until the new year.

Comment: @Zck Please let me know do you found the solution of "disallowed_useragent with Google Drive SDK". I have face the same problem.

Comment: solution is to stop using web views.

Comment: yea , i faced such issue and conclude the same , waiting for update

Comment: @RahulSaini ,yeah i found the solution just follow this link for sign in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating