# Integration error with Google drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-drive-api

I have tried to integrate Google Drive in my application and load all file names but every time I have the same this issue.

I have to fetch all file name of the drive. If a demo is available then it is the best help of me. I follow all steps which define in google developer console.

My error:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [403 Error - Thats an error. Error: disallowed\_useragent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654403/403-error-disallowed-useragent