# Login with Google Drive is not getting authorized

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

I'm refering the link

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name

To authenticate google drive with my application. I can do signing with google with `pod 'Google/SignIn'` but not with

```
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive', '~> 1.1.1'
pod 'GTMOAuth2', '~> 1.1.4'
```

As link suggest. Also I can see that the above google link says that **Last updated March 9, 2017.**
[image]

It seems like this code is now not is use but google doc is not updated. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I faced same problem.

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: I followed same code of above url, by creating my app in google console

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654403/403-error-disallowed-useragent/42045386#42045386

Comment: Yes with "GoogleSignIn" its working fine, Thanks but my query regarding that demo code provided in google link.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Google mustn't have updated the doc.

Although, they had [announced](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html?m=1) that authentication from embedded browsers is no longer supported, for improving app usability.

> In the coming months, we will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views”,

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html):

> "In the coming months, we will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views”, such as the WebView UI element on Android and UIWebView/WKWebView on iOS, and equivalents on Windows and OS X."

To help you migrate, they offer libraries and samples that follow modern best practices which you can use:

- **Google Sign-In** for [Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios), our recommended SDK for sign-in and OAuth with Google Accounts.
- AppAuth for [Android](http://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android), [iOS, and OS X](http://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS), an open source OAuth client library that can be used with Google and other OAuth providers. We also offer [GTMAppAuth](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth) (for iOS and OS X), a library which enables AppAuth support for the [Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest), and the [GTM Session Fetcher](https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher) projects.

You can also check the Github - [Introduction to the Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C for REST](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/wiki#authentication-and-authorization) to help you check on the updates for the Google API. There is also reported [issue](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4919) about this which you can follow to track on any updates on this.

Hope this helps.